# Swift 4 - Recognize "Finger pan from view to view"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So ***what I have*** is I have a UITapGestureRecognizer for a Tap on the view (lets call that base view) and a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on that same base view. When the user taps the view action one is dispatched and if the user holds down on the view another view pops up. This behavior works nicely.

***What I want*** to do is that the user does not have to separately tap the popup. Instead I want the user to just "pull up" on the popup and activate an action.

***I tried to*** use a UIPanGesture on the popup but that did not work.

**Edit**

I dragged the long press gesture recognizer on to the view (actually a key in a custom keyboard). This is the code

```
@IBAction func popupPressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Todo code for popupKey
}

@IBAction func keyPressedLong(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:

        popupTint = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        popupTint!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        popupTint!.alpha = 0.6

        self.view.addSubview(popupTint!)

        popup = UIView(frame: sender.view!.frame)

        popup.frame = CGRect(x: popup.frame.origin.x, y: sender.view!.frame.origin.y - popup.frame.height, width: popup.frame.width, height: popup.frame.height)
        popupKey.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        popupKey.clipsToBounds = true

        let popUpTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.popupPressed(tapGesture:)))
        popupKey.addGestureRecognizer(popUpTap)

        self.view.addSubview(popup)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Any Ideas ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps a bit of code at least.

Comment: I edited my post so you can read my code. Maybe that clarifies what I am on about =) @Kamran how would you use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer is continuous so you could use the location in the base view to move the popup & check if the movement threshold was met.

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didLongPress(gesture:)))
self.baseView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

@objc func didLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
     if self.popUpView.bounds.contains(gesture.location(in: self.popUpView)) {
          // perform action
     }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want the popup to move. I want to trigger an event when the (downpressed) finger is moved up on the popup.